# MS Access - Select rows according to a field whose values are in an array

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

I am using MS Access 2007.

I would like to extract data from a table in a database according to some field, say 'car ID'. For every 'car ID' (total of 100 cars), I want to extract all the rows related to that car into an excel spreadsheet in order to operate on it later. Ideally, I would have 100 different spreadsheets in the end, each describing the history of a single car.

Now, since I have a vector of 100 car IDs, I would like to select the car ID automatically as if it was within a for loop, rather than running a query manually 100 times.

I think I should use VBA for that, but since I am new to both MS Access and VBA I am not quite sure of how to handle this.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much.

Comment: In the second table, is all the data just characteristics of the specific car? For example, CarID = 1, data would be Red, 6 cyclinder etc... ?

Comment: The table contains historic information of 100 cars relative to, say, 1 year. So, for example, if we consider CarID=222, in this table we have 365 rows only related to CarID=222. Each row contains one value of interest, say, the km covered. Obviously, we have 365 rows for all the different other cars as well. All of the rows I am talking about are inside one single table. My objective is to extract the 365 rows related to each car in a single excel spreadsheets and do this for each car. I would end up with as many spreadsheets as the number of cars in the end, each of it containing 365 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need 2 tables. Your main table contains the CarID as the key field and the second table contains all our values/interests. It seems you are set up that way already.

For this example below, you will need to create a select query and save it with the name "mySavedQuery" (It doesn't matter what the select query does at this point because we will change it through the code.)

In the on-click of a command button you could do:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim strSQL As String
Dim intLow As Integer
Dim intHigh As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Set db = CurrentDb

intLow = 1
intHigh = DMax("CarID", "Table2")

For i = intLow To intHigh
    strSQL = "SELECT Table1.CarID, Table2.Interest FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.CarID = Table2.CarID " _
           & " WHERE (((Table1.CarID)=" & i & "));"
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

    If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
        rs.MoveFirst

        Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("mySavedQuery")
        qdf.SQL = strSQL

        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "mySavedQuery", "C:\Users\SClark\Desktop\Survey" & i & ".xls", True
    End If

Next i

Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
Set qdf = Nothing
```

What is happening here is we determine the minimum CarID = 1 and use the DMAX to find the Max CarID. We then iterate these values and export one Excel sheet per CarID.

This is a down and dirty example but should get you started down the right path...

Comment: Thanks a lot random_answer_guy! I got the idea and obtained what I was looking for.